# Can not hear Windows messages from an ActiveX object inside IE

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, com, activex

After some research I finally made my ActiveX object work, and now I want to listen Windows messages when someone modifies a value in a mixer control (Message number = 977)

The problem is that if I make my class inherit from class Form, it stops working in IE and as far as I know the only way to hear Windows messages is through a Form.

I have the vague idea of adding the methods and events to my ICOMEvents and ICOMMethods interfaces although I would like to know if there is a better way to do this or if its impossible.

Sample of my class, if it does not inherit from Form everything works right!

```
{Guid("ECA5DD1D-096E-440c-BA6A-0118D3516AAA")} _
{ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)} _
{ComDefaultInterface(GetType(ICOMMethods))} _
{ComSourceInterfaces(GetType(ICOMEvents))} _
Public Class Class1
'When inherited, can not call any method in IE
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form 
Implements ICOMMethods
```

Note: I can not make a Windows Form Control and make it compatible with ActiveX, my needs to be a class library.

Another way : I was also thinking in adding a Timer and checking every X seconds the volume level...not very neat but would be less painful as I already have all necessary methods for checking volume (XP,Vista and 7). Any comments on this or another approach could be very useful!

Way2 : Create a hidden windows form ?? (made some tests, not working)